# GCC #error that won't break further compilation

Tags: c++, gcc

I have several simple macros that exist in some files across a large project that includes a `#error`. They all follow this structure, more or less:

```
#ifdef COMPFAIL
#pragma message "Compilation Has Failed"
#error
#endif
```

I want to set the project up so that, if `COMPFAIL` is defined, the `#pragma` within each file occurs with compilation ultimately failing. I now understand that when `#error` is called, it halts compilation on the spot, not attempting to compile any of the other files defined in my Makefile and preventing all further `#pragma` calls from occurring. Is there a way to force the compiler to finish preprocessing across all files before failing?

Comment: I think you;re looking for `make -k` or equivalent, not any feature of the compiler itself.

Answer (score 2):

A very simple test:

```
#error foo
#error bar
```

Compiling this file with gcc produces the following results:

```
t.c:2:2: error: #error foo
#error foo

t.c:3:2: error: #error bar
#error bar
```

It's obvious that `#error` does not completely stop the compilation of the file. If it were, only the first error would've been reported, and the compilation would've stopped. But, after the `#error`, the compiler keeps going, and continues to preprocess, and compile, the rest of the code. However, it's pointless, since the compiler will not produce an object file, once an error occured, so it's not clear to me what benefit you expect to gain from continuing to preprocess this file.

Now, as far as any other files that gets compiled via your makefile, that's completely unrelated to what any pragma or directive does, insofar as compiling or preprocessing the rest of the file. Once a command executed by `make` terminates with a non-zero exit code, make stops executing any more commands. To change that, use the `-k` option, as it's already been mentioned.

Note, that the `-k` option has no direct relevance on whether `#error` does or does not abort the immediate compile at hand. Either way, the compile stops with a non-zero exit code, and that's the driving factor, here.

Comment: This depends on the compiler; it would be quite within its rights to halt compilation on the first `#error` (and as a programmar that's actually what I would prefer to see; if an `#error` has been hit then it's because of some serious problem that is rendering the rest of the file invalid).

Comment: Sure, but the question is explicitly referring to gcc.

Comment: I'm aware that #error allows for preprocessing of the current file to complete, this is the behavior I want. The point of continuing preprocessing is to print all TODO messages that exist throughout the project. The macro above is just a dumbed down version.